# PHP-FPM on Apache log issue

Tags: apache-http-server, php, logging, stderr, php.ini

I am having trouble finding the cause of my php-fpm process logging its error output to the same location as the script result.

I have an Apache server which passes requests to the php-fpm process using:

```
ProxyPassMatch [Regex to match] fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/php/script.php
```

The issue I encounter, is the html document returned looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>: Undefined array key... etc
  <br />
 </head>
 <body>
  Rest of html works as expected
 </body
</html>
```

Where the error messages encountered by php-fpm are being passed back to Apache along with the html output, and showing up in my web browser.

### Attempts to Source Issue

As the error message is originating with php-fpm, I have tried looking for the cause in the php-fpm conf file.

I run php-fpm as a daemon from its binary file with:

```
./php-fpm --allow-to-run-as-root
```

I confirm the location of the conf file is as I expect using:

```
./php-fpm -tt
```

which prints many lines of output appended by:

```
/srv/php/conf/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

confirming the location of the conf file in use.

The lines of the conf file I can see as relevant, pertaining to error logging, are:

```
[global]
error_log = log/php-fpm_error.log
log_level = debug

[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

user = myuser
group = mygroup

access.log = log/$pool_access.log
access.format = [default access string format]

slowlog = log/$pool_slow.log

catch_workers_output = 1
decorate_workers_output = no

php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = /srv/php/log/$pool_error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

I have tried adding the line `daemonize = no` to the `[global]` options and starting fpm. When a request is made, this only shows a single `event triggered` notice, not helping with my debug efforts.

### A solution, but why ?

As I was typing this question, I attempted adding the line:

```
php_flag[display_errors] = off
```

And this has both prevented PHP errors from logging to the result passed to Apache, as well as begun logging the errors into the file `/srv/php/log/$pool_error.log`.

The default configuration file states that the options `php_flag`, `php_admin_flag`, etc, are for overwriting values set by php.ini. My question is, since I have no php.ini file, I would expect there to be nothing to overwrite. Perhaps these values are set when I configure PHP pre-build ? Any suggestions as to the solution here would be appreciated.

Additionally, I haven't been able to find any documentation online about how PHP-FPM goes about passing its result to Apache. Does Apache listen to stdout ? Are the errors logged to stderr, and then directed to the stated log file ? If so, why were errors being passed to stdout before I fixed my issue ?

Thankyou !

Comment: How come you have no php.ini file? Are you planning to do all configuration at FPM pool level? (Don't do that; it will cause headaches with extensions, not to mention certain parameters that can only be specified at ini-file level.)

Comment: I am only running PHP as an fpm process, I believe this should be entirely configured by my conf file containing the `[global]` and `[pool name]` headings. You mention certain parameters may only be set within the `.ini` file - when I run `./php-fpm -tt`, the only configuration file mentioned is `/php-fpm.conf` containing `[global]` and `[pool name]` - are you suggesting php-fpm reads a configuration file from elsewhere ?

Comment: Yes, *all* PHP runtimes read the same kind of php.ini as their primary source of configuration – this includes FPM as well, not only CGI or mod_php. Take a look at their phpinfo() output. I'm mentioning this because 1) a specific setting I needed last week was listed as "php.ini only" and could not be set via any other "override" mechanism (apparently FPM pool settings merely have the same weight as httpd.conf settings), and 2) I've tried loading PHP extensions per FPM pool and that only resulted in crashes, and others told me that it had to be done via php.ini globally.